# How to change the visibility of a scatterlineseries programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radhtmlchart

I am using Telerik RadHtmlChart, specifically the Scatter Line chart, and have run into an issue with changing the visibility of a series in the code-behind. I would like to access certain series and turn their visibility to false. I know Telerik recently implemented this control, or something similar, but I cannot find documentation on how to achieve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the Visible property of the series, something like:

```
RadHtmlChart1.PlotArea.Series(1).Visible = False
```

Comment: Yep, that worked for me! I was forgetting to add the index to the series() part.